# Community user can not edit or update record from mobile app using SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS

Tags: oauth2, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, connected-apps, customer-community, ios

**Configuring My Org to have community and connected app -**

- Created a community in my org.
- Created a connected app.
- Cloned "Customer Community User" profile and enabled "API Enabled" named this profile as "Cloned Customer Community User Plus API Enabled"
- Than I added "Cloned Customer Community User Plus API Enabled" profile in connected app as a member.

**Configuring mobile app -**
Configured sample app available with SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS "RestAPIExplorer" iOS app to be able to access my org, this steps involves

- Adding my "RemoteAccessConsumerKey","OAuthRedirectURI" and adding "SFDCOAuthLoginHost" entry in iOS app.

Community user is able to login from mobile app, he is also able to fetch data but as I try to hit patch request or post request, I get error thrown by SDK. I believe that community user don't have access to updating data. Looks like its a bug. Can anybody confirm this ?

Comment: which objects are you updating ?Please be specific

Comment: It's not working with system object or any custom object. I believe its a bug in SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS. I tried to update using data with "PATCH" request by postman rest client or directly iOS NSURLConnection rest request, I was able to do successfully. But it failed If I use "sendRESTRequest" of SFRestAPI.